# Dynamically prevent opening a page if someone else is actively using it

Tags: javascript, django

I am using Django for backend, and normal HTML/CSS/JavaScript for frontend without any interactive UI libraries like React.

**Current Approach:**

I have a page that contains a form to edit instance X as an example. If someone opens this page for editing, I am adding a value in my database that this instance is locked by this editor. After he finalizes editing, he should press "save" or "close" button to unlock it for others.

**Problem:**

If the editor didn't save and forgot to "close", the instance will remain locked till he come back and close it.

**Required Approach:**

But, I want to dynamically prevent the others to open it because someone is actively editing X now. By "actively" word, I mean that this user is using the page now, and the page tab is active in his browser. So, if he just closes the tab or browser, or leaves the tab inactive for maybe 5 minutes, I want to unlock the instance for editing.

Comment: You may user the websockets (with, for instance, https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), where browser will notify backend that it is still active. Or user JavaScript to detect idle of the user and send a request to backend (I am not really sure about that), or set some timer for the lock, after which it will be released.

Comment: Actually, I dun like the timer lock as it is still not dynamic approach. But I will check the websockets option. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can also record the time when the last change was made. If the user for example writes something then you extend the time in the background using ajax for example. Every time the page is opened it checks if the time of the last edit is greater than 5 minutes. If it is, the form is open for editing and the person who previously edited it and left the tab open and inactive gets the information that the editing time has passed. He gets this information when trying to save or immediately.

Comment: just add field to model that user is editing. like edited_now_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE). So the field is null at the beginng. When user try tu open view for editing chcek if the filed is none or it has the request.user. If True show the form else show message that the item is edited by someone else. If user saves or cancel set model field to None.

Comment: @Martinez, I cannot rely on that, as the form is huge, and the editor may be active for let's say 15 minutes and he is still editing, so it will be inconvenient as I am going to revoke the edit access from him after 5 minutes.

Comment: @WaldemarPodsiadło, what if the user didn't do anything after opening the form for editing? he may leave the tab open forever without clicking on cancel or save.  I want to revoke the access depending on inactivity. And please check my last reply on Martinez too.

Comment: @YasserMohsen my bank has something similar. When I am not doing anything for 15 minutes there is a popup that my session is going to expire in 2 minutes and by clicking on that popup I can extend that time. Otherwise logout.